# Grep string in a file containing colon

Tags: linux, unix, grep, command

I have following string in a multi-line file

```
.....<other lines>
-classpath "${ROOT}/abcjars/*:${ROOT}/lib/*" \
.....<otherlines>
```

I want to check if classpath line is present in file or not

If I try following grep command it works properly,

```
grep '\-classpath \"${ROOT}/abcjars/*' $File
```

But if I add colon (:) in search pattern it doesn't work

```
grep '\-classpath \"${ROOT}/abcjars/*:' $File
```

I want to grep and check if entire line is present or not. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular expressionm, `*` has special meaning, it means to match the preceding character zero or more times. But in your file you don't have `:` immediately after a sequence of `/` (because `*` is between them), so it's not matching.

You're not doing any regular expression pattern matching, so you should use the `-F` option to specify that this is a fixed string.

```
grep -F -e '-classpath "${ROOT}/abcjars/*:' $File
```

The `-e` option is needed to allow a search string that begins with `-`, otherwise the search string is treated as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Use escaping character

```
grep '\-classpath \"${ROOT}/abcjars/\*:' $File
```

If still same issue, try using grep regexp flag

Comment: It's not the colon that needs escaping, it's the asterisk.

Comment: There's no need to escape `"`, BTW.