# Grep: How to grep for a string containing a colon

Tags: regex, grep

I want to grep for a string which begins with a colon `:`, the contains 0 or more characters of anything, and then ends with the string `mystring`.

I tried this: `grep -rI ':*mystring' .` but this did not work.

From searching, I believe the reason this does not work is because it is matching "0 or more instances of the colon character `:` followed by `mystring`. ([See an answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58596765/grep-string-in-a-file-containing-colon))

That doesn't make much sense to me, hence my question.

*Edit:* None of the answers in the linked question solve this problem. There is no mention of matching a colon character, and trying to adapt the answers does not work either.

Comment: You just need `grep -rI '^:.*mystring'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, do you want to add this as an answer with some explanation?

Comment: Perhaps you expected it to behave like a glob? Regex and wildcards follow different rules and you'll be hard pressed to find two tools following the same rules for regex.

Comment: See [Regular expression to match string starting with a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240504/regular-expression-to-match-string-starting-with-a-specific-word)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
grep -rI '^:.*mystring' file
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `:` - a colon
- `.*`  - any zero or more chars
- `mystring` - a string.

Comment: Also, in case you are not using a GNU `grep`, see [Grep regular expression not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240179/grep-regular-expression-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Bizzarely this actually doesn't work on the system I am using. Sorry for the delay in reply I was away from my desk

Comment: Try searching for `: public className` and compare to grepping for `^:.*className' - unless there is a bug in my version of grep they give different results

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/RNYFWG). Install a GNU `grep`.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't install anything on this machine as I don't have admin access for it

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Ok, then use `awk`: `awk '/^:/ && index(tolower($0), "classname")' file`